# Not passing Lighthouse audits for Angular PWA as a sub-directory of website - start_url not fetching

Tags: angular, https, service-worker, angular-service-worker, lighthouse

I have a website and I have a PWA located in a sub-directory of the website. For instance, if my website is `https://elves.com/#/` I have my PWA located in `https://elves.com/app/#/`. As you can probably tell from this I am using hashbanging in my website and PWA. I am trying to pass the Lighthouse audits for PWA but am failing.

These are the audits I am failing:

`Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url`

`Current page does not respond with a 200 when offline`

`start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline
Unable to fetch start URL via service worker.`

I feel like I have tried every combination of scope_url and start_url in the `manifest.json`.

For scope_url I have tried:

- `https://elves.com/app/`
- `https://elves.com/app/#/`

For start_url I have tried:

- `https://elves.com/app/`
- `https://elves.com/app/#/`
- `./index.html`

I have `<base href="/app/#/">` set in my `index.html`

I have `"index": "/app/index.html",` set in my `ngsw-config.json`

Comment: Where do you place your service worker? Is it at Root level or inside a subfolder?

Comment: I have it within my /app/ directory since that is where my app is located on my website

Comment: A service worker is limited to its domain and to the folder where it is physically saved. SWs are usually stored at root level to avoid potential path problems. have you tried moving it at root level?

Comment: Tried `scope_url = "/app/"`? If you make a prod build and serve the app locally with a web server (ng serve does not work with service worker), do you get any warnings/errors?